How to delete a part of a mesh of a multires object?
So I have imported a mesh with multires already on the mesh and I have deleted a part of the mesh in edit mode but the mesh still appears unchanged in object mode.

This is the mesh in object mode.

This is the mesh in edit mode and the multires modifier as well. There are no additional modifiers applied to this mesh. The mesh also looks like the second pic in sculpt mode as well.
I have tried to apply the modifier and then try to remove the head but that does not work as well.
So is there anyway to "force" the mesh in object mode to be the same as the one in edit mode.
Thanks for your time.

Perhaps a stupid idea, but did you try and deactivate the Multires modifier (unticking the "screen" icon) in Object Mode, then reactivate it ? Just in case some data are cached and should be updated after modifications on Edit Mode...

I have tried that and it is still the same, head in object mode, no head in edit mode

I ended up doing retopology for this model.

Doing retopology may not be a good answer here, it is basically redoing the whole model. The part you want to delete can be hidden in the edit mode.
